# How many bit strings of length $8$ have $3$ x's in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

A strings of length $8$ using the letters x and y only

1) How many of these strings have exactly $3$ x's? So it's $\binom{8}{3} = 56$

2) How many of these strings have 3 x's in a row?

I don't know how to handle that case, so for that one the order matters. So in my opinion it should contain $P(8,3) = 8 \times 7 \times 6 = 336$. But I should have something to deduct from that, I am confused.

Thank you!

Comment: Easier to count the strings that do not have three $X's $ in a row.  Such a string must end in exactly one of $Y,YX, YXX$ (if it has length at least $3$) so you can count these recursively.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.